# The jump parameter decreases negatively in the Unity Animator when game is started

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the game starts in Unity the jump value decreases in the Animator and continues to do so infinitely.
I was not sure the reason for the negative value decreasing. Ibelieve my character possesses a Rigidbody and a collider.
I was not able to fix the issue. I have enclosed the UserControl and ThirdPersonCharacter script

```
ThirdPersonCharacter.cs

using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson
{
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(CapsuleCollider))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class ThirdPersonCharacter : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] float m_MovingTurnSpeed = 360;
[SerializeField] float m_StationaryTurnSpeed = 180;
[SerializeField] float m_JumpPower = 12f;
[Range(1f, 4f)][SerializeField] float m_GravityMultiplier = 2f;
[SerializeField] float m_RunCycleLegOffset = 0.2f; //specific to the character in sample assets, will need to be modified to work with others
[SerializeField] float m_MoveSpeedMultiplier = 1f;
[SerializeField] float m_AnimSpeedMultiplier = 1f;
[SerializeField] float m_GroundCheckDistance = 0.1f;

Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;
Animator m_Animator;
bool m_IsGrounded;
float m_OrigGroundCheckDistance;
const float k_Half = 0.5f;
float m_TurnAmount;
float m_ForwardAmount;
Vector3 m_GroundNormal;
float m_CapsuleHeight;
Vector3 m_CapsuleCenter;
CapsuleCollider m_Capsule;
bool m_Crouching;


void Start()
{
m_Animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
m_Capsule = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
m_CapsuleHeight = m_Capsule.height;
m_CapsuleCenter = m_Capsule.center;

m_Rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationY | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationZ;
m_OrigGroundCheckDistance = m_GroundCheckDistance;
}


public void Move(Vector3 move, bool crouch, bool jump)
{

// convert the world relative moveInput vector into a local-relative
// turn amount and forward amount required to head in the desired
// direction.
if (move.magnitude > 1f) move.Normalize();
move = transform.InverseTransformDirection(move);
CheckGroundStatus();
move = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(move, m_GroundNormal);
m_TurnAmount = Mathf.Atan2(move.x, move.z);
m_ForwardAmount = move.z;

ApplyExtraTurnRotation();

// control and velocity handling is different when grounded and airborne:
if (m_IsGrounded)
{
HandleGroundedMovement(crouch, jump);
}
else
{
HandleAirborneMovement();
}

ScaleCapsuleForCrouching(crouch);
PreventStandingInLowHeadroom();

// send input and other state parameters to the animator
UpdateAnimator(move);
}


void ScaleCapsuleForCrouching(bool crouch)
{
if (m_IsGrounded && crouch)
{
if (m_Crouching) return;
m_Capsule.height = m_Capsule.height / 2f;
m_Capsule.center = m_Capsule.center / 2f;
m_Crouching = true;
}
else
{
Ray crouchRay = new Ray(m_Rigidbody.position + Vector3.up * m_Capsule.radius * k_Half, Vector3.up);
float crouchRayLength = m_CapsuleHeight - m_Capsule.radius * k_Half;
if (Physics.SphereCast(crouchRay, m_Capsule.radius * k_Half, crouchRayLength, Physics.AllLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
{
m_Crouching = true;
return;
}
m_Capsule.height = m_CapsuleHeight;
m_Capsule.center = m_CapsuleCenter;
m_Crouching = false;
}
}

void PreventStandingInLowHeadroom()
{
// prevent standing up in crouch-only zones
if (!m_Crouching)
{
Ray crouchRay = new Ray(m_Rigidbody.position + Vector3.up * m_Capsule.radius * k_Half, Vector3.up);
float crouchRayLength = m_CapsuleHeight - m_Capsule.radius * k_Half;
if (Physics.SphereCast(crouchRay, m_Capsule.radius * k_Half, crouchRayLength, Physics.AllLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
{
m_Crouching = true;
}
}
}


void UpdateAnimator(Vector3 move)
{
// update the animator parameters
m_Animator.SetFloat("Forward", m_ForwardAmount, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
m_Animator.SetFloat("Turn", m_TurnAmount, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
m_Animator.SetBool("Crouch", m_Crouching);
m_Animator.SetBool("OnGround", m_IsGrounded);
if (!m_IsGrounded)
{
m_Animator.SetFloat("Jump", m_Rigidbody.velocity.y);
}

// calculate which leg is behind, so as to leave that leg trailing in the jump animation
// (This code is reliant on the specific run cycle offset in our animations,
// and assumes one leg passes the other at the normalized clip times of 0.0 and 0.5)
float runCycle =
Mathf.Repeat(
m_Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime + m_RunCycleLegOffset, 1);
float jumpLeg = (runCycle < k_Half ? 1 : -1) * m_ForwardAmount;
if (m_IsGrounded)
{
m_Animator.SetFloat("JumpLeg", jumpLeg);
}

// the anim speed multiplier allows the overall speed of walking/running to be tweaked in the inspector,
// which affects the movement speed because of the root motion.
if (m_IsGrounded && move.magnitude > 0)
{
m_Animator.speed = m_AnimSpeedMultiplier;
}
else
{
// don't use that while airborne
m_Animator.speed = 1;
}
}


void HandleAirborneMovement()
{
// apply extra gravity from multiplier:
Vector3 extraGravityForce = (Physics.gravity * m_GravityMultiplier) - Physics.gravity;
m_Rigidbody.AddForce(extraGravityForce);

m_GroundCheckDistance = m_Rigidbody.velocity.y < 0 ? m_OrigGroundCheckDistance : 0.01f;
}


void HandleGroundedMovement(bool crouch, bool jump)
{
// check whether conditions are right to allow a jump:
if (jump && !crouch && m_Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Grounded"))
{
// jump!
m_Rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(m_Rigidbody.velocity.x, m_JumpPower, m_Rigidbody.velocity.z);
m_IsGrounded = false;
m_Animator.applyRootMotion = false;
m_GroundCheckDistance = 0.1f;
}
}

void ApplyExtraTurnRotation()
{
// help the character turn faster (this is in addition to root rotation in the animation)
float turnSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(m_StationaryTurnSpeed, m_MovingTurnSpeed, m_ForwardAmount);
transform.Rotate(0, m_TurnAmount * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}


public void OnAnimatorMove()
{
// we implement this function to override the default root motion.
// this allows us to modify the positional speed before it's applied.
if (m_IsGrounded && Time.deltaTime > 0)
{
Vector3 v = (m_Animator.deltaPosition * m_MoveSpeedMultiplier) / Time.deltaTime;

// we preserve the existing y part of the current velocity.
v.y = m_Rigidbody.velocity.y;
m_Rigidbody.velocity = v;
}
}


void CheckGroundStatus()
{
RaycastHit hitInfo;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
// helper to visualise the ground check ray in the scene view
Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f) + (Vector3.down * m_GroundCheckDistance));
#endif
// 0.1f is a small offset to start the ray from inside the character
// it is also good to note that the transform position in the sample assets is at the base of the character
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), Vector3.down, out hitInfo, m_GroundCheckDistance))
{
m_GroundNormal = hitInfo.normal;
m_IsGrounded = true;
m_Animator.applyRootMotion = true;
}
else
{
m_IsGrounded = false;
m_GroundNormal = Vector3.up;
m_Animator.applyRootMotion = false;
}
}
}
}
```

```
ThirdPersonUserControl.cs

using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (ThirdPersonCharacter))]
    public class ThirdPersonUserControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private ThirdPersonCharacter m_Character; // A reference to the ThirdPersonCharacter on the object
        private Transform m_Cam;                  // A reference to the main camera in the scenes transform
        private Vector3 m_CamForward;             // The current forward direction of the camera
        private Vector3 m_Move;
        private bool m_Jump;                      // the world-relative desired move direction, calculated from the camForward and user input.

        
        private void Start()
        {
            // get the transform of the main camera
            if (Camera.main != null)
            {
                m_Cam = Camera.main.transform;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning(
                    "Warning: no main camera found. Third person character needs a Camera tagged \"MainCamera\", for camera-relative controls.", gameObject);
                // we use self-relative controls in this case, which probably isn't what the user wants, but hey, we warned them!
            }

            // get the third person character ( this should never be null due to require component )
            m_Character = GetComponent<ThirdPersonCharacter>();
        }


        private void Update()
        {
            if (!m_Jump)
            {
                m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
            }
        }


        // Fixed update is called in sync with physics
        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            // read inputs
            float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            float v = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");
            bool crouch = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C);

            // calculate move direction to pass to character
            if (m_Cam != null)
            {
                // calculate camera relative direction to move:
                m_CamForward = Vector3.Scale(m_Cam.forward, new Vector3(1, 0, 1)).normalized;
                m_Move = v*m_CamForward + h*m_Cam.right;
            }
            else
            {
                // we use world-relative directions in the case of no main camera
                m_Move = v*Vector3.forward + h*Vector3.right;
            }
#if !MOBILE_INPUT
// walk speed multiplier
       if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) m_Move *= 0.5f;
#endif

            // pass all parameters to the character control script
            m_Character.Move(m_Move, crouch, m_Jump);
            m_Jump = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well without going made if m_ForwardAmount = move.z; then if you move backwards z will be negative.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the velocity of Y decreases and my world center of mass decreases also